# How can I insert a previous input value into a textarea?

Tags: html, css

I'm new to HTML/CSS and have created a simple contact form to enter a name, number, and have a populated `textarea` with a short message but would like to automatically populate the `name` area within the text field with whatever was put into the name's input field previously in the contact form. What is the best way to do this?

```
<fieldset>
<h1>Contact Form</h1>
<label for="name">Patient Name:</label>
<input name="name" id="name" type="text" size="40" maxlength="100">
<label for="number">Patient Number:</label>
<input name="number" id="number" type="text" size="40" maxlength="12">
<label for="message">Text Messge:</label>
<textarea name="message" id="message" cols="40" rows="10">
Hi [name], thank you for visiting us!
</textarea>
<input class="btn" name="submit" type="submit" value="Send">
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Why would you want "hi [their name], thank you for visiting us!" to appear in the message they send to you?

Comment: I called it a contact form, but it's for my company to use to fill in the name and number for the message to be sent to

Comment: Here's the general idea http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VpYmWb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some JavaScript should solve your problem.

Insert this `script` tag into your HTML file **after** the form.

```
<script>
  // save the location of the name field
  var name_field = document.getElementById('name');

  //add an event listener to activate if the value of the field changes
  name_field.addEventListener('change', function() {
    // when the field changes run the following code

    // copy the text (value)
    var name = name_field.value;

    // concatenate it with the desired message
    var autoFill = 'Hi ' + name + ', thank you for visiting us!';

    // and paste it into the message field.
    document.getElementById('message').value = autoFill;
  })
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

For dynamic behavior you are gonna need some javascript.

```
<input name="number" id="number" type="text" oninput="getNumber()" size="40" maxlength="12">

 <script>
var getNumber = function() {
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "Hi " + document.getElementById("name").value + ", thank you for visiting us";
}
</script>
```

And as it looks right now, you probably shouldn't be using a textArea to display this message, rather use a paragraph element.
AngularJS is perfect for a scenario like this if you are more interested.

Comment: As well as Ajax